# Load all objects into Results variable (Realm iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, database, realm

I am trying to take all the preloaded data that I entered into Realm Database and use it in my app. The problem I am having is that I am not able to load all the objects into a Results variable of my custom type. I have 530 entries in my preloaded database and none of them are showing up in the View Controller.

[image: Preloaded Database with streetListings]
This data in stored in /Database/streetListings.realm

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class StreetListing: Object {
  
  @objc dynamic var houseNumber: String?
  @objc dynamic var streetName: String = ""
  @objc dynamic var trashDay: String = ""
  
  convenience init(houseNumber: String?, streetName: String, trashDay: String) {
    self.init()
    self.houseNumber = houseNumber
    self.streetName = streetName
    self.trashDay = trashDay
  }
}
```

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  
  var realm: Realm!
  var streetListings: Results<StreetListing>?
  
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let realmPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "streetListings", withExtension: "realm")!
    let realmConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(fileURL: realmPath, readOnly: true)
    realm = try! Realm(configuration: realmConfiguration)
    streetListings = realm.objects(StreetListing.self)
  }
}
```

```
(lldb) po realmPath
▿ file:///Users/raz/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3A4F3C1A-9C15-4AF0-B211-5125E3843075/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/B1331B06-EDFE-494C-A170-7FDB1B2CA291/NorthTrash.app/streetListings.realm
  - _url : file:///Users/raz/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3A4F3C1A-9C15-4AF0-B211-5125E3843075/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/B1331B06-EDFE-494C-A170-7FDB1B2CA291/NorthTrash.app/streetListings.realm

(lldb) print realmConfiguration
(RealmSwift.Realm.Configuration) $R32 = {
  _syncConfiguration = nil
  _path = "/Users/raz/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3A4F3C1A-9C15-4AF0-B211-5125E3843075/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/B1331B06-EDFE-494C-A170-7FDB1B2CA291/NorthTrash.app/streetListings.realm"
  _inMemoryIdentifier = nil
  encryptionKey = nil
  readOnly = true
  schemaVersion = 0
  migrationBlock = nil
  deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded = false
  shouldCompactOnLaunch = nil
  maximumNumberOfActiveVersions = nil
  customSchema = nil
  disableFormatUpgrade = false
}


(lldb) po streetListings
▿ Optional<Results<StreetListing>>
  ▿ some : Results<StreetListing> <0x7fbd2e607140> (

)
    - rlmResults : RLMResults<StreetListing> <0x7fbd2e607140> (

)
```

If anyone can help me out with this that would be great. Thank you!

Comment: If you don't get useful answers and you can't wait, perhaps consider reproducing the problem by making a small project and add it to your Github so that we can play with it.

Comment: I am not seeing anything really wrong with your code. In fact and pretty much copy an pasted it ans it works correctly for me. You may have an issue with the path? Other than that - looks ok.

Comment: I think it has to do with the custom object class of StreetListings. I check to see if database is empty and it is not. However my <Results> variable is empty...

Answer (score 0):

I have also worked on Realm Project.
Here is simple tip for loading all Object.

```
 let realm = try? Realm()
       let personData = realm?.objects(Person.self)
      //write code for loading personData
```

Comment: That's pretty much the same code as in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Loading lot of objects can take time. Try accessing `streetListings` after a delay. Not sure why you need the database to be readOnly. If not, you can use NotificationToken to listen to changes made to the realm database.

Comment: The database needs to be readOnly because user will lookup streetListings. They should not have permission to change the database. Maybe there is another way of looking up data without using Realm...

Comment: There's not a lot of objects; 530 is nothing. In fact, it it as 53,000 it would still load in milliseconds because Realm objects are lazily loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work. I changed my custom class from 'streetListings' to 'StreetListings'. Also created a brand new Xcode project and transferred all the existing files.